# How to get a crate break/shatter when falling from a high distance in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I already have a crate in my scene that can break after I shoot is a couple of times. But I want to add the feature of breaking when the crate falls from a high distance.
FYI  I am new to C# and unity so I can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm guessing you are using `OnCollisionEnter` if so try
[Collision.relativeVelocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html)

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //Do some check here to see if bullet hit.
    //if there was a collision and it was not a bullet
    if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 2) //2 is arbitrary 
    {
        //break your crate
    }
}
```

Comment: For performance reasons, it's recommended to use `Vector3.sqrMagnitude` instead of `Vector3.magnitude` whenever possible to avoid calculating square roots.